# VBA Append unique regular expressions to string variable

Tags: excel, regex, vba, function, dictionary

How can I grab matching regular expressions from a string, remove the duplicates, and append them to a string variable that separates each by a comma?

For example, in the string, "this is an example of the desired regular expressions: BPOI-G8J7R9, BPOI-G8J7R9 and BPOI-E5Q8D2" the desired output string would be "BPOI-G8J7R9,BPOI-E5Q8D2"

I have attempted to use a dictionary to remove the duplicates, but my function is spitting out the dreaded #Value error.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong here? Or is there any suggestion for a better way of going about this task?

Code below:

```
Public Function extractexpressions(ByVal text As String) As String
Dim regex, expressions, expressions_dict As Object, result As String, found_expressions As Variant, i As Long

Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
regex.Pattern = "[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][-]\w\w\w\w\w\w"
regex.Global = True

Set expressions_dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

If regex.Test(text) Then
    expressions = regex.Execute(text)
End If

For Each item In expressions
    If Not expressions_dict.exists(item) Then expressions_dict.Add item, 1
Next

found_expressions = expressions_dict.items

result = ""

For i = 1 To expressions_dict.Count - 1
    result = result & found_expressions(i) & ","
Next i

extractexpressions = result

End Function
```

Comment: Call your function from a Sub and you'll be able to debug it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try that. Does the general logical flow and application of the dictionary method seem sound?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call your function from a Sub you will be able to debug it.

See the comment below about adding the matches as keys to the dictionary  - if you add the match object itself, instead of explicitly specifying the match's `value` property, your dictionary won't de-duplicate your matches (because two or more `match` objects with the same `value` are still distinct objects).

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Debug.Print extractexpressions("ABCD-999999 and DFRG-123456 also ABCD-999999 blah")
End Sub


Public Function extractexpressions(ByVal text As String) As String
    Dim regex As Object, expressions As Object, expressions_dict As Object
    Dim item
    
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    regex.Pattern = "[A-Z]{4}-\w{6}"
    regex.Global = True
    
    If regex.Test(text) Then
        Set expressions = regex.Execute(text)
        Set expressions_dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For Each item In expressions
            'A dictionary can have object-type keys, so make sure to add the match *value*
            '  and the not match object itself
            If Not expressions_dict.Exists(item.Value) Then expressions_dict.Add item.Value, 1
        Next
        extractexpressions = Join(expressions_dict.Keys, ",")
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Wow, this was the key that brought it all together: "A dictionary can have object-type keys, so make sure to add the match *value"

Thanks so much! I still have some learning to do with respect to dictionaries

Comment: That's a common mistake with dictionaries that I've made many times in the past...

Answer (score 0):

VBA's regex object actually supports the backreference to a previous capture group. Hence we can get all the unique items through the expression itself:

```
([A-Z]{4}-\w{6})(?!.*\1)
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/HyOUJH/1)

---

To put this in practice:

```
Sub Test()
    Debug.Print extractexpressions("this is an example of the desired regular expressions: BPOI-G8J7R9, BPOI-G8J7R9 and BPOI-E5Q8D2")
End Sub

Public Function extractexpressions(ByVal text As String) As String
    
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Pattern = "([A-Z]{4}-\w{6})(?!.*\1)|."
    .Global = True
    extractexpressions = Replace(Application.Trim(.Replace(text, "$1 ")), " ", ",")
End With
    
End Function
```

Prints:

[image]

Comment: **Note**: This works if the order in which the substrings appear does *not* matter.